# Return value of function in C

Tags: c, recursion, return-value

```
int ret(char *)
{
    //nothing    
}

int main(void)
{
   printf("%d\n",ret("foo"));
}
```

Why does the Function ret returns a garbage value ???

and

```
int my_strlen(char *s)
{
   if(*s)
      return 1 + my_strlen(s + 1); // or my_strlen(s+1) + 1;
}
```

in the above function , if i am not wrong , my_strlen should always return Junk value
when condition fails (i.e whenever it reaches to '\0') as there is no else case or any return statement for false case. So for any valid string it should
always return 1 + junk value. But it doesn't . It works fine. It gives exact length of Any
string. Why doesn't it return junk value like the function "**ret**" does ???
Kindly clear my doubts. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanx..

Answer (score 8):

In both cases, it is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). From section *6.9.1 Function definitions* of the C99 standard (draft N869), clause 12:

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

A subset of undefined behaviour is to *appear* to work correctly, which is what is witnessed in the second code snippet.

Comment: "Why does my program act strange when I do something totally nonsensical and unreasonable???"

Comment: @Jim: I suspect you are ridiculing the OP, but it is not an unreasonable question. Many objects in this world are designed to be safe even when used incorrectly, such as a microwave that shuts off when you open the door. This question comes from the premise, possibly unconscious, that a computer is similar; it is designed to respond sensibly in all circumstances. It is a reasonable premise because we seek to design user-level software this way. So it understandable that we have to teach people that programming languages do not have this feature.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I agree individual cases might be a curiosity, but they are all variations of a question that has the same answer; undefined behavior.  After the first few dozen of these, it gets kind of old, and I don't think much new is learned if yet another strange example is dredged up.

Comment: @Jim, the more there are, the greater the chance some poor soul stumbles upon from a google search.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, by the way, you should try a necktie.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the general lack of respect of your question.

The real answer is that on Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler your code compiles with a "warning".  I copied your code and fixed what was probably a typo on your part:

```
   // Here, I added the variable X
   int ret(char *X)
   {
       //nothing
   }

   int main(void)
   {
      printf("%d\n",ret("foo"));
   }
```

and got the following message:

```
   c:~\eclipsecdt\compilererrormsg\main.c(15) : warning C4716: 'ret' : must return a value
```

Hopefully, this message explains what you need to do to fix your code.  The reason why you are getting garbage is because of something called "the stack" and the fact that an integer has not been place onto it because you have not issued a `return 0;` (or non-zero if you want) statement.

Hope this helps.